# Batch script to watch for changes on FTP server

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I want to make a batch script able to listen to my ftp server and download files to my computer every time a new file is uploaded on the ftp server.

Any ideas? I use WinSCP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) with its [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
:Loop
winscp.com /command ^
    "option batch abort" ^
    "open <session>" ^
    "synchronize local <local directory> <remote directory>" ^
    "exit"
timeout 10
goto :Loop
```

---

*On Windows XP and older, use `ping -n 10 127.0.0.1` instead of `timeout 10`.*

---

*See also:*

- *[WinSCP FTP setting to continuously monitor changes and download](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20372868/850848) and*
- *WinSCP article [Keep local directory up to date (download changed files from remote SFTP/FTP server)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_keep_local_directory_up_to_date).*

Answer (score 1):

Use the /synchronize local switch of WinSCP. It will check the remote server and download any files that don't match a local directory.

```
 winscp.exe [session] /synchronize local [ <local directory> [ <remote directory> ] ]
```

Then you can use task manager to run it on a schedule or use it in a batch file in a loop

ex:

```
 :Loop
 winscp.exe [session] /synchronize local [ <local directory> [ <remote directory> ] ]
 ping -n 10 127.0.0.1
 goto :Loop
```

will run it every 10 seconds.

Read the [Command line options](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) for WinSCP for more.

Comment: I do not see how this could possibly be automatic. You are missing `/defaults` switch + you cannot skip the Synchronization checklist window anyway.

Comment: Ok, it looks like it may be just a syntax error on your side instead; as I see you have copied the synchronize arguments from the `synchronize` scripting command syntax, not `/synchronize` command-line argument. So you were probably on a right track. Anyway, see my answer for proper syntax.