# WinSCP FTP setting to continuously monitor changes and download

Tags: ftp, download, monitor, winscp

We are two developers working from different country. I want WinSCP to continuously monitor changes in FTP directories and when my partner modify any file, I want it to automatically download the changes to my local directory.

Comment: Simply - updated timestamp is newer than yours, so WSCP is downloading an updated file. I'd recommend you setting up a git repository and prepare autodeploy script.

Comment: oops, you make me confused totally :) how to do all that.

Comment: There's a plenty of tutorials about automatic deployment after git pushing. Make some research. BTW: I wonder how it was possible you neither overwritten each other's changes. :P

Comment: actually he is at master and i am on slave. He make changes and i download, he don't inform me about changes but i need to inform him about changes, so i need to download changed file automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As @eRIZ commented, using WinSCP for this task may not be an ideal solution. Using revision control system, such as git, would be a way better.

Anyway to answer your question:

- Setup a synchronization script. You will need to use the [`synchronize local`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) command in particular. For general instructions, see the guide to [automating file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).
- Schedule the script to run in regular (frequent) intervals using Windows Windows Scheduler. See the guide to [scheduling file transfers (or synchronization) to FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

See also [Batch script to watch for changes on FTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16239371/850848) or WinSCP article [Keep local directory up to date (download changed files from remote SFTP/FTP server)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_keep_local_directory_up_to_date).